# Como remover espaços entre linhas de uma tabela?

Tags: html, email

Estou fazendo um e-mail de *marketing*, e está tudo normal na *versão web*, mas quando faço o envio ele fica com um espaço em branco entre as linhas da tabela.

Link do e-mail marketing na versão web. http://leoamaraldev.com.br/job/jul16/emkt-adao3/

[image: Não deveria ficar essa linha branca]

Comment: Tentou usar `border: 0px`? Tenta com `table`,`td` e `tr`

Comment: O link me pareceu perfeito, sem espaço, foi corrigido?

Comment: Coloca `vertical-align: top` na imagem.

Comment: No link está normal mesmo, o problema é só quando envia o e-mail.

Comment: Funcionou a dica do Peter Parker, obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi seguindo a dica do Peter Parker de colocar `vertical-align: top;` na imagem!